# Pythonesque bit-slicing in Verilog?

Tags: bit-manipulation, verilog, system-verilog

In Python, I can select even or odd bits like this:

```
>>> bits = ['a','b','c','d'];
>>> bits[0::2]
['a', 'c']
>>> bits[1::2]
['b', 'd']
```

It would be very practical if I could do this in Verilog, so that I wouldn't have to expand the expression and do it manually. Expanded (i.e. `{a[0], a[2]}` and `{a[1], a[3]}`), it obviously wouldn't work with my otherwise parameterized wire set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with a generate block. Example:

```
wire [FLOORS-1:0] RELEVANT;

genvar i;
generate
    for (i=0; i<FLOORS; i=i+1) begin
        assign RELEVANT[i] = FLOOR_REQUEST[i*2+FORWARD];
    end
endgenerate
```

- `FLOORS` is the width of the output wire (half the width of the input wire).
- `RELEVANT` is the result.
- `FORWARD` is the even/odd selector (0 or 1).
- `FLOOR_REQUEST` is the input.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mechanism in Verilog or SystemVerilog to do a bit slice like the Python example you gave.  That is, you cannot specify a step of 2 between bits.

You can do this with a for-loop, and it doesn't need to be in a generate block like in your own answer.

Modified example from your answer:

```
always @(*) begin
   for (int i = 0; i < FLOORS; i++) begin
      RELEVANT[i] <= FLOOR_REQUEST[i*2+FORWARD];
   end
end
```

This should synthesize okay as long as `FLOORS` is a constant.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution require that RELEVANT is a reg? Would it synthesize to a flip-flop in this case?

Comment: It would need to declared as a reg type, but that does not automatically mean it will synthesize to a flop. In this case it would not.